# How can I ensure a cron task is executed only once in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, cron, nestjs, scheduled-tasks

I'm using NestJS.
I have a cron task that needs to run every 10 seconds. However, I need to ensure that the second task doesn't start if the first task is still running. In other words, the task should only be executed once at a specific moment in time. Additionally, if the task takes too long to complete, I would like to forcefully terminate its execution.

I couldn't find such a function in the @nestjs/schedule documentation. Perhaps someone already has a ready solution in the form of a decorator or in another form. I would appreciate it if you could share it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class SchedulingService {
  @Cron('*/10 * * * * *', {name: 'schedulerTest'})
  async schedulerTest() {
    await this.testService.testFunc();
  }
}
```

How can I ensure a cron task is executed only once in NestJS?

Comment: Use a queue https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a simple variable like `running:boolean = false`. Set this to true inside your cron if it start - and back to false if it down.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class SchedulingService {
  
  running:boolean = false;

  @Cron('*/10 * * * * *', {name: 'schedulerTest'})
  async schedulerTest() {
    if (!running) {
      this.running = true;
      await this.testService.testFunc();
      this.running = false;
    }
  }
}
```